# Update task 'Next start time' with PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, scheduled-tasks, winforms

I have a PowerShell script that pops-up a GUI on users computers every 60 minutes, if they **don't** click a SUBMIT button within 15 minutes, it sends an SMS to an emergency contact. (The script is for the safety of the employees, to make sure they are okay)

The user manually opens a .bat file which will start a task in Task Scheduler that opens the script every 60 minutes. The script contains a timer that countdowns from 15 minutes, I want to be able to restart the task timer once they click the SUBMIT button.

For example: If the script window pops up on their computer, they click SUMBIT when there is 5 minutes left, I want the task timer to reset to 'Repeat in 60 minutes'.

I'm hoping its a simple cmdlet that I can include in a '**$Button.AddClick({#cmdlet})**'

I hope this makes sense, any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Without script it is going to be really hard to come up with any solution. Doesn't have to be the entire script, just the part with the popup and timer are required.

Comment: you can simply add the next trigger via New-ScheduledTaskTrigger https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/new-scheduledtasktrigger?view=windowsserver2019-ps

Comment: @SimonS Thank you for this, this will probably work, I'll update once I get it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @SimonS for leading me down the right path I was able to find a very simple solution.

```
$button.Add_Click({
    $ts = New-TimeSpan -Minutes 60
    $hour = (get-date) + $ts
    $taskChange = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -At $hour -Once
    Set-ScheduledTask -TaskName "Start_CheckIn" -Trigger $taskChange
})
```

Comment: Also I forgot to mention, in order to this you need Admin privilege's to change the task settings, so make sure to run the task with highest privileges in task scheduler, and set the -ExecutionPolicy Bypass switch, thats the only way I was able to achieve this